# why boolean modifier not making difference

Tags: modifiers

Im modeling a car and with some shape im getting a difference. With the boolean modifier with the difference selected its not getting cut. I have remove double of the mesh and of the shape yet to no result i found. Any suggestion.

[image]

[image]

Comment: as usual with booleans, check also normals and negative scale of involved objects

Comment: @m.ardito sorry forgot to mention there i have check normals and negative scale

Comment: @m.ardito i have attach my file plz check

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ateks,the file had several issues:

1. car body had no boolean(?)
2. car body had several unapplied modifier mirror > subsurf > edge split - those were interfering after adding a boolean modifier (it showed an error), so I applied them all
3. the bars HAD negative X scale(corrected)
4. the bars also had edge split modifier (I applied it)

in this way I could obtain this:

[image]

which should be more or less what you wished, I hope.

Here is the modified file 
[image]

Comment: It work but all modifier has to apply. Any other method without applying i can cut. Thanks